# How to set Angular2 cli baseurl for a new web site?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular-cli, typescript2.0

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC web site.  www.foo.com
I want to create a whole new sub system of our site using Angular2 and I want it to go under www.foo.com/NewSubSystem.

I have downloaded the Angular2 Cli from https://cli.angular.io/.
When I run from the command line

```
ng build -dev
```

The output has all the javascript script tags looking this in the index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

I need the scr="www.foo.com/NewSubSystem/inline.bundle.js"

NOTE:  I have tried to update the baseURL in the tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "www.foo.com/NewSubSystem"
}
```

but this does not seem to make any difference.

Any suggestions or pointers would be nice.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the index file baseref
    base href="NewSubSystem/"
Then just code like its the root.
I reset the baseref to dist/ with javascript depending on the env sensed

Comment: Found out what my problem was...   I had node v6.4.1 and I needed node v6.9.1.      Now with the latest node version, ng build --base-url "NewSubSystem" creates the correct mapping.

Comment: I ment to type   ng build --base-href NewSubSystem/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am on node 6.3 and wondering why everything went to h***. It seems you have to watch the gitter feed 24/7 or you are going to be out of luck :(

Answer (score -1):

Change your index.js files update

```
<base href="/<you base url>/">
```

if you are working with webpack: 
You should also update the file config/webpack.common.js, so that you assets folder content can be hosted from your new baseurl.

```
 ...
   const METADATA = {
   title: 'ng2-admin - Angular 2 Admin Template',
   description: 'Free Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4 Admin Template',
   baseUrl: '/<you base url>/',
   isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
 };
.....
```